# Projectivization of $H^0$ as a symmetric power

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $\pi:X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be a regular elliptic surface with a section $\sigma$.

I am interested in this claim:

> $\mathbb{P}H^0(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(n))\cong \operatorname{Sym}^n(\sigma) $ by associating to a section the set of points where it vanishes.

The statement only makes sense I guess if $n\ge 0$ (otherwise the left hand side would be empty). I feel like it is true in a more general setting (outside the scope of elliptic surfaces) but don't know where to start.

Thank you for any hints or references.

Comment: It's a fairly standard fact that $\operatorname{Sym}^n(\mathbb P^1) \cong \mathbb P^n$ (see next comment), and of course the image of $\sigma$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$. I suppose the main thing to notice is that the vanishing locus of a section is invariant under the $\mathbb C^*$-action (i.e. $t\cdot 0 = 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb C^*$), so the indicated map $H^0(\mathbb P^1, \mathcal O(n)) \to \operatorname{Sym}^n(\sigma)$ descends to the projectivization.

Comment: As for the first isomorphism, this MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68687/symmetric-powers-of-a-curve-projective-bundle-over-jacobian-and-the-relative discusses how the symmetric power is a projective bundle over the Jacobian, but the latter is a point for $\mathbb P^1$ so the symmetric power is just a projective space, hence we just need to find its dimension. But $\operatorname{Sym}^n(\mathbb P^1) = (\mathbb P^1)^{\times n} /\mathfrak S_n$ i.e. it is the quotient of an $n$-dimensional variety by a finite group hence also of dimension $n$.